# Access table to add a new row

Tags: controllers, module, table

I created a new module `softcopy`. and also created a new table with six fields of name `softcopy_softcopy`.

I am trying to access the table so that I can add a new row with some data which I have in controller.

So, I tried the below code in `softcopy` controller:

```
echo Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->getTable('softcopy/softcopy');
```

I got the following error in `var/report`:

> a:5:{i:0;s:47:"Can't retrieve entity config: softcopy/softcopy";i:1;s:1469:"#0

How should I access my newly created table in my controller?

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Efk_Softcopy>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </Efk_Softcopy>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>            
            <Efk_Softcopy>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Efk_Softcopy</module>
                    <frontName>softcopy</frontName>
                </args>
            </Efk_Softcopy>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <models>
            <softcopy>
                <class>Efk_Softcopy_Model</class>
            </softcopy>
        </models>
        <blocks>
            <softcopy>
                <class>Efk_Softcopy_Block</class>
            </softcopy>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

Comment: can you post the `config.xml` of your module?

Comment: @Marius updated post with config.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the resource model declaration and the table declaration.
Change the `<models>` section of your config file to this:

```
<models>
    <softcopy>
        <class>Efk_Softcopy_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>softcopy_resource</resourceModel>
    </softcopy>
    <softcopy_resource>
        <class>Efk_Softcopy_Model_Resource</class>
        <entities>
            <softcopy>
                <table>softcopy_softcopy</table>
            </softcopy>
        </entities>
     </softcopy_resource>
</models>
```

You should also create a resource model for your model, and don't insert values directly in the db. Use the internal api:

```
Mage::getModel('softcopy/softcopy')->setData(...)->save();
```

---

<sub>I'm starting to feel like I'm spamming this website, but I recommend again using a [module creator](https://github.com/tzyganu/moduleCreator) and you won't have these issues again</sub>

Comment: yeah I thought to use your module creator but thought I don't need much files here. but It seems I need them now.. thanks. I am checking now

Comment: Try first with what I suggested in the answer. Maybe it works and you don't need an additional tool anymore

Comment: I mean no disrespect to you, module creator really helped alot in my project i.e more than 30%. but it creates some unnecessary files like `.csv`, `.xml` and `.phtml` which I don't need and also it creates a menu in admin panel and also a section in system->configuration.. I am getting scolds from my above people saying "why are you creating unnecessary sections?".. so, I thought to do it on my own by referring a module created using module creator... :)

Comment: NO problem. I understand that my module cannot fit everyone's needs, but in my opinion is easier to remove the unnecessary files than to build the same thing over and over again. Anyway...you know better what you need. :)

Comment: The thing is I don't know which code to remove for unnecessary sections. your module creator is amazing though.. :)

Comment: I tried your suggestion. Still I get the same error. By referring your module, I created the following directory: "sql" -> `efk_softcopy_setup` -> `installer-1.0.0.0.php` folder in it and also I added the following code in config.xml: `<global><resources>
            <efk_softcopy_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Efk_Softcopy</module>
                    <class>Efk_Softcopy_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </efk_softcopy_setup>
        </resources>`. but still I am getting the same error. I even cleared the cache.

Comment: Hey leave it.. I am using your module creator.. Thanks :)

Comment: Marius, I created module using module creator.. still I can't able to save data in the table... please check [here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/18253/2960) whenever you have time.