# Unable to save data in table

Tags: magento-1.8, model, module

I am calling the below function in controller to check whether adding row to a table works or not.

```
public function urlAction(){
    echo "hello";
    $_orderId = "32" ;
    $enc_key = "somekeyhere";
    $model = Mage::getModel('softcopy/softcopy');
    $model->setData(
        array( 'order_id' => $_orderId,
        'key' => $enc_key,
        'downloads_count' => 0
    ))->save();
}
```

In the above function, I can see "hello" text for a millisecond then the page is redirecting to error reporting page.

The error states as follows:

> a:5:{i:0;s:59:"The URL key contains capital letters or disallowed symbols.";i:1;s:1298:"#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\xyz\app\code\local\Efk\Softcopy\Model\Resource\Softcopy.php(210): Mage::throwException('The URL key con...')

FYI, I created the module using Ultimate module creator.

PS: The `softcopy_softcopy` table has the following fields:

```
 entity_id
 order_id
 key
 downloads_count
 date (current_time_stamp)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you selected the option to create url rewrites for your module.  In case you don't need it, just edit the file `Efk\Softcopy\Model\Resource\Softcopy.php` and completely remove the method `_beforeSave()` from it. That should solve it.

Comment: yes I stupidly kept url rewrites enabled.. and wasted my time as always.. thanks.

Comment: Marius, How to load a specific row data from the table? I tried this which is not working: `Mage::getModel('softcopy/softcopy')->loadByAttribute('order_id', $_orderId)`..

Comment: Try with `$row = Mage::getModel('softcopy/softcopy')->load($_orderId, 'order_id');`

Comment: yes worked.. not sure I am being cross or magento is cross.. :/ Thanks again.